# Что означают сокращения MVC, MVP и PM?

Tags: mvc, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования

В заметках по разработке пользовательских интерфейсов часто встречаются аббревиатуры MVC, MVP, PM. Откуда они взяты и что означают?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это сокращения с английского.

- MVC - Model View Controller
- MVP - Model View Presenter
- PM - Presentation Model

Идея этих шаблонов в том или ином разделении между подсистемами, взаимодействующими с пользователем и бизнес-логикой. Одним из широко известных примеров реализации подобных шаблоном является библиотека WPF из .NET.

Хорошую статью на русском можно прочитать там: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd419663.aspx.